# Как перезаписать контекст вызова функции bind?

Tags: javascript

Перезаписал свою функцию `bind`:

```
Function.prototype.myBind = function(obj) {
    let fn = this,
        slice = Array.prototype.slice,
        args = slice.call(arguments, 1); //
    return function() {
        return fn.apply(obj, args.concat(slice.call(arguments))); //
    }
}
```

Как можно перезаписать контекст вызова функции `bind`, чтобы он не привязывался конкретно к объекту?

То есть, допустим есть 2 объекта:

```
let obj1 = { age: 20 };
let obj2 = { age: 33 };
```

И функция:

```
let func = function() { return this.age; };
```

При привязки с помощью `bind` у нас будет:

```
func = func.myBind (obj1);
func(); // => 20;
```

Я хочу перезаписать функцию, и чтобы она выводила age obj2:

```
func = func.bind(obj2);
func(); // => тоже вернет 20, но надо что было вернуло 33
```

Без понятия как это сделать. Пробовал сохранять как-то контекст вызова в instance, но не получается.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656593/javascript-function-bind-override-how-to-bind-it-to-another-object

Comment: Опубликовал в виде ответа

Answer (score 1):

Перепривязать функцию нельзя.

Из спецификации [ES2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-function-prototype-object) про `Function.prototype.bind`:

> **19.2.3.2 Function.prototype.bind ( thisArg , ...args)**
>
> [...]
>
> Note 2: If Target is an arrow function or a bound function then the thisArg passed to this method will not be used by subsequent calls to F.

Если вы хотите вызывать свою функцию для разных объектов, то вам достаточно просто хранить "чистый" вариант своей функции и привязывать ее к тому объекту, для которого функцию нужно вызывать. Например:

```js
let obj1 = { age: 20 };
let obj2 = { age: 33 };

let func = function() { return this.age; }; 

let func1 = func.bind(obj1);
let func2 = func.bind(obj2);

console.log(func1());
console.log(func2());
```

Англоязычный вариант ответа: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656593/javascript-function-bind-override-how-to-bind-it-to-another-object